# Timer not updating every second in javasricpt

Tags: javascript

This is my code to display a countdown timer for a otp, but its displaying only static value and is not getting updated every second like expected.

```
<?php 
// Set the target end time (in this example, 10 minutes from now) 
$endTime = time() + (10 * 60);  
 
// Calculate the remaining time 
$remainingTime = $endTime - time(); 
 
// Display the remaining time 
echo "<span id='countdown'></span>"; 
 
?> 
 
<script> 
// Display the remaining time in minutes and seconds 
function displayCountdown() { 
  var remainingTime = <?php echo $remainingTime; ?>; 
  var minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60); 
  var seconds = remainingTime - (minutes * 60); 
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"; 
  remainingTime--; 
  if (remainingTime < 0) { 
    clearInterval(interval); 
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time's up!"; 
  } 
} 
var interval = setInterval(displayCountdown, 1000); 
</script>
```

Please point out what am I missing.

Comment: Either the `remainingTime` is zero, or you have a syntax error. Please post the code after the php has executed (for example from "show source" in the browser) so we can decide

Answer (score 1):

Remember, PHP code is executed on server - and won't be able to affect JS ("browser-time") execution. Your JS function, effectively, looks like this:

```
<script> 
// Display the remaining time in minutes and seconds 
function displayCountdown() { 
  var remainingTime = 600; // generated by PHP and inserted into script before sending it to browser
  var minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60); 
  var seconds = remainingTime - (minutes * 60); 
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"; 
  remainingTime--; 
  if (remainingTime < 0) { 
    clearInterval(interval); 
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time's up!"; 
  } 
} 
var interval = setInterval(displayCountdown, 1000); 
</script>
```

Here, the problem is immediately visible: you only decrement `remainingTime` during a single run of `displayCountdown` function. The next time it's called, the value is again 600 - as `remainingTime` variable is local.

Therefore, the most straightforward solution is to move that variable outside of `displayCountdown` scope, like this:

```
<script> 
var remainingTime = <?php echo $remainingTime; ?>;

function displayCountdown() { 
  var minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60); 
  var seconds = remainingTime - (minutes * 60); 
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"; 
  remainingTime--; 
  if (remainingTime < 0) { 
    clearInterval(interval); 
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time's up!"; 
  } 
}

var interval = setInterval(displayCountdown, 1000); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to move the remaining time calculation from displayCountdown func. And the remaining time will be updated by the setInterval() method (every second). I hope this helps for you.

```js
<?php 
$endTime = time() + (10 * 60);  
 
echo "<span id='countdown'></span>"; 
 
?> 
 
<script> 
function displayCountdown() { 
  var remainingTime = <?php echo $endTime - time(); ?>;
  var minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60); 
  var seconds = remainingTime % 60; 
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"; 
  if (remainingTime <= 0) { 
    clearInterval(interval); 
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time's up!"; 
  } 
} 

displayCountdown(); 

var interval = setInterval(displayCountdown, 1000); 
</script>
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: I update code, please check may be this time works!

Answer (score 0):

You are defining remaining time in the function, so it will be 10 minutes every time the function is called.

You need to move the `var remainingTime = <?php echo $remainingTime; ?>;` 
to above the function. Like this:

```
var remainingTime = <?php echo $remainingTime; ?>; 
function displayCountdown() { 
    var minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60); 
    var seconds = remainingTime - (minutes * 60); 
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"; 
    remainingTime--; 
    if (remainingTime < 0) { 
        clearInterval(interval); 
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time's up!"; 
    } 
} 
var interval = setInterval(displayCountdown, 1000);
```

Then it won't get overwritten every time the interval calls the function